# Generic conversion to Numeric

Tags: scala, generics, data-conversion

I would like to write a generic conversion function converting a sequence of `Double`s into any `Numeric` class, something along the lines of:

```
  def construct[T : Numeric](a: Seq[Double]): Seq[T] = {
    val n = implicitly[Numeric[T]]
    a.map { value =>
      value
      ???
    }
  }
```

The inverse is easy, using `Numeric` `toDouble`, but I did not find a way how to do this direction. How can that be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is `n.fromInt(value.toInt)`, but if you don't want to lose precision your are out of luck with `scala.math.Numeric`. I would suggest implementing your own type class:

```
trait Num[T] { def fromDouble(d: Double): T }

object Num { implicit val wateveryouneed = ... }    

def construct[T](a: Seq[Double])(implicit n: Num[T]: Seq[T] =
  a.map(n.fromDouble)
```